# Using Queryband with RODBC in R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, rodbc, r-server

i use R for statistical analysis at work and just set up a R Server with RStudio (or a Server with R would be more correct) i managed to create a connection with RODBC to our **Teradata database**. So far so good.

Now our administrator would like to add a Queryband with some parameters to our SQL query. That is no problem using SQL directly but does not work with RODBC in R it seems.
If i am correct the problem ist that, sqlQuery() always stops after the sep ";" therefore the additional information from the queryband is not send along with the SQl query.

I tried with different versions that normally work e.g. using a multiqueryfunction, but nothing worked
I thought maybe parametereized queries could solve this but i couldn't make that work.
Any suggestions? Is there maybe a package that can help?

Code: (with db_connection from odbcConnect())

```
#load package
library(RODBC)

sqlQuery(
   db_connection, query = 
   "SET QUERY_BAND ='USER=MyID;ABT=AS;'
   FOR SESSION;
   SELECT
   * 
   FROM MyData; 
   SET QUERY_BAND = NONE FOR SESSION;"
)
```

Comment: Please format your code correct. Use markup.

Comment: like that? not used to posting Code

Comment: Teradata or SQL Server?

Comment: @user9193191 `inline code`

Comment: It's a Teradata Database.